# How do I read push ID of a specific child?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I am trying to make an Android application first time using the Firebase Realtime Database.

Comment: Did you see the Firebase documentation on [reading a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events)? That should be helpful here. --- If you tried that already and can't get it to work, edit your question to show the minimal, standalone code that reproduces where you are stuck. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get the Id of the object at a specific index (like your want to find the id where name is web (just an example))

try the below piece of code

```
private void getPushId() {
        database.getReference()
                .child(NODE_NAME)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            try {
                                YourModel model = snapshot1.getValue(YourModel.class);
                                if (model.getName().equals("YOUR_SPECIFIC_NAME")) {
                                    snapshot1.getKey(); // Save in Mutable Object
                                    break;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the value of the `name` field that exists in the objects in the `Domains` node, then you should create a reference that points to that node and perform a `get()` call, as seen in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference domainsRef = db.child("Domains");
domainsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", name);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
Android
Web
Flutter
```

Comment: Hey Imran. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?